# Communicate through a VPN link using Arduino UART WiFi Module

Tags: networking, arduino, wifi, vpn, uart

The following describes the configuration of the system and other details. The problem is mentioned after that. If the initial description is too much or not needed, please skip it.

[image]

I have a VPN (between two SIMs). One SIM is in a USB dongle, the other one is in a WiFi router. The dongle is connected to computer 'A', and another computer ('B') is wirelessly connected to the WiFi router which can access the dongle. The VPN is between the router and the computer 'A' (dongle). As the WiFi router leases 'B' a private IP, 'A' can't ping 'B'. But 'B' can ping 'A'. There is no issue up to now.

I have created a socket-based simple Java network application (client - server pair). The client is running on 'B', the server is running on 'A. Only the client can send data to the server, the other way around is not possible. This part also is OK. Now I need to replace the computer 'B' with an Arduino. I need to send some data from the Arduino to computer 'A' through the same network.

For this, the Arduino needs a WiFi module to access the router. I've [this USART WiFi module with the shield](http://www.emartee.com/product/42121/Stackable%20Uart%20WiFi%20Module%20Kit). It can successfully connect to the router, (I can ping it from a computer, which is also connected to the router).

---

**THE PROBLEM**

Now the configuration is as below.

[image]

There's the (server) application running on computer 'A', which is listening on a given port (port 8090). How can I send some data (eg. some text "hello!"), from the Arduino to the computer 'A'?

Please note that for [the WiFi module I'm using](http://www.emartee.com/product/42121/Stackable%20Uart%20WiFi%20Module%20Kit), I found some examples for applications based on the Arduino WiFi shield. But I can't apply them to my configuration (can I?).

Comment: The router doesn't know whether device B is a computer or Arduino.  Whatever connections are possible with one, the other should also be able to make.  I don't think you have an Arduino issue here.  This seems wrong >>Only client can send data to the server, other way is not possible.<<  A TCP/IP connection requires data transmitted both ways.

Comment: but how can we ping an private ip (eg. 192.168.1.100) from outside? it's not possible.(may be without creating a kind of virtual network)

Comment: There are several things not making sense. You said you are using a VPN, a virtual private network?  A VPN acts as a **tunnel** and makes a device on the WAN side appear to be on the LAN side.  Computer A should be given an IP address that is part of the private LAN address space.  Show some IP addresses in the question to help explain what you are doing.